# Chrome PDF Viewer embedded download button not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, coldfusion

Clicking the Chrome PDF Viewer download button directly downloading the server-side file.

I'm using ColdFusion server to generate the pdf file and view it in a separate tab with inline. PDF was correctly viewing in a tab but when clicking the download icon I can able to download that PDF file, it was downloading my .cfm file.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did anyone have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping 'inline' with 'attachment', in your Content-Disposition header.

Basically, inline will try, always varying by borwser, to open the file inside the browser. In any case what you're trying to do you should definitely use attachment. This will directly go to the user and force a download.

Comment: I'm using this CF code <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#Chr(34)##LOCAL.fileName##Chr(34)#">
 <cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#LOCAL.filePathWithName#">

Comment: But most of the persons were love to click download icon to get the PDF file.

Comment: Try swapping 'inline' with 'attachment', in your Content-Disposition header.

Comment: Basically, inline will try, always varying by borwser, to open the file inside the browser. In any case what you're trying to do you should definitely use attachment. This will directly go to the user and force a download.